# Obtain Class from Jackson TypeReference

Tags: java, reflection, jackson

I have some code which needs to unpick a Jackson TypeReference to find out if it is a Collection.  At the moment the best I can come up with is:

```
// Sample type reference - in reality this is an argument to the method
final TypeReference<List<String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<String>>(){};

// Obtain the Java reflection type from the TypeReference
final Type type = typeRef.getType() instanceof ParameterizedType ? ((ParameterizedType)typeRef.getType()).getRawType() : typeRef.getType();

// Obtain the name of the class (or interface)
final String typeName = type.toString().replace("class ", "").replace("interface ", "");

// And find out if it is a Collection
final boolean isCollection = Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(Class.forName(typeName));
```

But I would hope that there is a way to do this without string manipulation.  Is there a better way to go from the Java `Type` to the `Class`, or indeed to check assignability directly from either the `TypeReference` or the `Type`?

This needs to work on Android so any features added in Java 8 can't be used.

Comment: Can you just cast the type returned in second line to a Class? (Class)typeRef.getType()

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately I can't cast it because typeRef.getType() return a Java `Type` not a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your line of code,

```
final Type type = typeRef.getType() instanceof ParameterizedType ? ((ParameterizedType)typeRef.getType()).getRawType() : typeRef.getType();
```

You can safely cast it to a Class like this

```
final Class clazz = (Class)(typeRef.getType() instanceof ParameterizedType ? ((ParameterizedType)typeRef.getType()).getRawType() : typeRef.getType());
```

To add a little more explanation -

In the first scenario where ( typeRef is an instance of ParameterizedType), you are retrieving the rawType which would be a Class.

In the second scenario where (typeRef is not an instance of ParameterizedType), it would still be a regular Class because it is not Parameterized.

Comment: Thanks; I was casting too soon when I tried this before and was attempting to cast a `ParameterizedTypeImpl` to a `Class` which is why it wasn't working before.